# What's the difference between WITH CTE & WITH CTE (<column_names>)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, cte

As shown in [Using Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) on MSDN, you can define a CTE as:

```
WITH expression_name [ ( column_name [,...n] ) ]
AS
( CTE_query_definition )
```

and use it like:

```
SELECT <column_list> FROM expression_name;
```

Let's say I have following 2 CTEs

```
with cte1 as(
select name from Table1
)

with cte2(name) as(
select name from Table1
)
```

A query outputs the same results for both CTEs as the inner query is same. The only difference between these two is that *cte2* has column name(`(name)`) defined in its declaration.

When I execute both CTEs, I don't see any difference in the execution plan.

I am just curious to know:

- What difference does it make if I don't specify any column names in CTE definition?
- Why I should/should not specify column names while creating CTE?
- Does it affect query execution plan by any chance? (As far as I have seen, it doesn't make any difference.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You nearly have the answer for one of your questions already.

In the [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) page, there is a line directly after your quote that explains this:

> The basic syntax structure for a CTE is:
>
> WITH expression_name [ ( column_name [,...n] ) ]
>
> AS
>
> ( CTE_query_definition )
>
> **The list of column names is optional only if distinct names for all resulting columns are supplied in the query definition.**

*(Emphasis added)*

This would mean that you would need to specify column names in a few situations:

- This would work:

  ```
  WITH [test_table] ([NoName], [CAST], [Function]) 
  AS
  (
      SELECT 
          1
        , CAST('1' AS CHAR(1))
        , dbo.CastToChar(1)
  )
  SELECT * FROM [test_table];
  ```
- as would this:

  ```
  WITH [test_table]  
  AS
  (
      SELECT 
          1 as [NoName]
        , CAST('1' AS CHAR(1)) as [CAST]
        , dbo.CastToChar(1) as [Function]
  )
  SELECT * FROM [test_table];
  ```
- But this would not as it does not have distinct names for the columns:

  ```
  WITH [test_table] 
  AS
  (
      SELECT 
          1
        , CAST('1' AS CHAR(1))
        , dbo.CastToChar(1)
  )
  SELECT * FROM [test_table];
  ```

Comment: essentially, the version without columns is the same as the version with column except SQL has to "infer" the column names from the query.

Answer (score 12):

Anecdotally, I prefer to name the columns inside the CTE instead of inside the `WITH CTE (xxx) AS`<sup>[1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23371/why-should-a-cte-start-with-a-semi-colon)</sup> clause since you'll never inadvertently mismatch the names vs the column contents.

Take for instance the following example:

```
;WITH MyCTE (x, y)
AS 
(
    SELECT mt.y
         , mt.x
    FROM MySchema.MyTable mt
)
SELECT MyCTE.x
     , MyCTE.y
FROM MyCTE;
```

What does this display?  It shows the contents of the `y` column under the heading of `x`, and the contents of the `x` column under the heading `y`.

With this realization, I *never* specify the column names in the `(xxx) AS` clause, instead I do it like this:

```
;WITH MyCTE
AS 
(
    SELECT Alias1 = mt.y
         , Alias2 = mt.x
    FROM MySchema.MyTable mt
)
SELECT MyCTE.Alias1
     , MyCTE.Alias2
FROM MyCTE;
```

This removes all doubt about what the column definitions are.

On a totally unrelated side-note; [always specify the schema name when referencing object names](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix), and [end your statements with a semi-colon](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).

Comment: right on!  I came here wondering if there were performance differences between the two syntaxes, BECAUSE I accidentally made this exact swap of columns while refactoring something.  And wondered -- Do I really need to do this?  I already use the SELECT col1 AS colName syntax anyhow.  So I'm done with naming columns in a CTE definition.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Ultimately each column needs a valid name and you can assign it in two ways:

1. Column list

   ```
   ;WITH cte (foo)
   AS
   ( select col from tab )
   select foo from cte;
   ```
2. Using original column names or aliases

   ```
   ;WITH cte
   AS
   ( select col from tab )
   select col from cte;
   ```

When you do both *alias* and *column list*

3. Both column list & aliases

   ```
   ;WITH cte (foo, bar)
   AS
   ( select col1         -- not valid in outer Select
            col2 as colx -- not valid in outer Select
     from tab )
   select foo, bar from cte;
   ```

This is similar to the definition of a View or a Derived Table, where you can specify a list of column names, too.

*column list*: When you have lots a complex calculations it's easier to spot the name, because they're not scattered through the source code. And it's easier if you got a recursive cte and you can you assign two different names for the same column in #3.

*original name/aliases*: You only have to assign an alias if you do a calculation or want/must to rename a column

Comment: "easier to spot" is perhaps a bit subjective.  I prefer to have the column aliases at the start of the line, as in `SomeAlias = SomeFunction(SomeColumn)`, with only one column definition per line.  This allows a simple scan down the left side of the column list to locate the one you're looking for.

Comment: @MaxVernon: That's right, and adding blank lines between calculations spanning multiple lines also helps. In fact I mostly omit the column list, too...

Comment: Funny that you mentioned views. I've never used the column list after the view name when defining a view, as in `CREATE VIEW SomeView (ColA, ColB, …) AS …`. Now that you've brought that up, I'm thinking of scenarios like `CREATE VIEW MyView (G) AS WITH cte (C) AS (SELECT A AS B FROM MyTable) SELECT E AS F FROM (SELECT C AS D FROM cte) AS s (E);` – what a joy to debug that would be!